# Why it suffices to prove that $h(a)=g(a)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $h(a)=1$?

Tags: several-complex-variables

> $h:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a homogeneous plurisubharmonic function. Assume $g:\mathbb{C^n}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is another homogeneous function. If we have to prove that $h(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}^n$, why it suffices to prove that $h(a)=g(a)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $h(a)=1$?

Since $h,g$ are homogeneous $h(\lambda z)=|\lambda|h(z)$ and $g(\lambda z)=|\lambda|g(z)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and any $z\in \mathbb{C}^n$. So we are done for $z\in \mathbb{C}^n$ which are of the form $\lambda a$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. But how about other elements? I came across this problem while reading a proof in a SCV book. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It does not suffice to prove that $h(a)=g(a)$ for **some** $a$ with $h(a)=1$, but it would suffice to prove it for **every** such $a$. I hope that the latter is what your book actually does.

Comment: Ok, ya that's my bad. The book indeed mention it for any such $a$. But still I dont get why it suffices.

Comment: And what do mean by "latter"? Do you refer it to my try of the OP?

Comment: The latter is "prove it for every such $a$."

Comment: Ok, but why does it suffices. I'm still confused.

Comment: Unless $h$ is trivial, the $a$'s with $h(a)=1$ and their multiples $\lambda a$, will constitute a dense set, because they're all the points $b$ where $h(b)\neq0$.